# c++ Append to linked list

Tags: c++

I'm writing a piece of code to append a node to the end of a singly linked list, but it seems that it doesn't append anything at all. Can anybody give me some idea of what I'm doing wrong?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Node{
        int val;
        Node* next;
        Node(int v) : val(v), next(NULL) {}
};

void append(Node &head, int d){
        Node n = head;    
        while(n.next != NULL){
                n = *n.next;
        }
        Node end(d);
        n.next = &end;
}

int main(){
        Node head(0);
        for(int i=1;i<5;i++){
                append(head, i);
        }    
        Node n = head;
        while(n.next != NULL){ //print the linked list, result is 0
                cout << n.val<<" ";
                n = *n.next;
        }
        cout<<n.val<<endl;
        return 0;
}
```

EDIT: I changed the append() method to append a dynamically-allocated node each time, but it still doesn't work.

```
void append(Node &head, int d){
            Node n = head;    
            while(n.next != NULL){
                    n = *n.next;
            }
            Node* end = new Node(d);
            n.next = end;
    }
```

Comment: I think, it would be nice if down-voters could leave a comment, this would help the OP in future

Comment: `n.next = &end`, `end` is a local variable so `&end` is an illegal pointer after `end` gets destroyed. You need to use dynamic allocation

Comment: Post on code review if you wish to learn what's wrong with the question.

Comment: @FlyingGambit What do you expect for a question without a clear problem statement? _"What I'm doing wrong?"_, or _"still doesn't work"_ are quite vague.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ A comment by the down-voter would allow him to rectify his mistake, no comments would leave him and/or possibly others scratching their head. After reading your comment, the OP would understand that he needs to construct his questions correctly to explain his problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few issues with this.

You make a copies in your `append` function here `Node n = head;` and here `n = *n.next`. You then then finally make a change to the copy rather than the original.

You are assigning `Node end(d)` on the stack. When `append` returns it goes out of scope and is deleted.

You can fix both with,

```
#include<iostream>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

struct Node{
    int val;
    std::shared_ptr<Node> next;
    Node(int v) : val(v), next(nullptr) {}
};

void append(Node &head, int d){
    Node* n = &head;    
    while(n->next != nullptr){
            n = n->next.get();
    }
    n->next = std::make_shared<Node>(d);
}

int main(){
    Node head(0);
    for(int i=1;i<5;i++){
            append(head, i);
    }    
    Node n = head;
    while(n.next != nullptr){
            cout << n.val<<" ";
            n = *n.next;
    }
    cout<<n.val<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You append the **local** object `Node end(d);` to the end of the linked list. This object is destroyed upon exist from `append` and the last list element points to a non-existent object.

Answer (score 2):

For the edited Question:
You are **copying** the `head` to `n`, then modify `n`. At the end of your `append` function, `n` is destroyed, but `head` was never touched.